# SQL display different data from the same table in different rows

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm trying to get a list of systems from our inventory software (in this case SCCM) from one view (v_gs_softwarefile) but with multiple criteria. In this particular case, I need all systems (SCCM calls the unique identifier "ResourceID", so i just stuck to that one) which do not have iexplore version > 8 and on the other side have a saplogon.exe with the exact version '7100.3.13.1045'.

Version 1 (Question: How can I output the filename and fileversion of saplogon.exe result?)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.ResourceID
    ,t1.FileName
    ,t1.FileVersion    
FROM
    v_GS_SoftwareFile as t1 
WHERE 
    (t1.filename = 'iexplore.exe'
    and
    t1.fileversion < '8.0')
    and
    t1.resourceid in (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            t2.resourceid
        FROM
            v_gs_softwarefile as t2
        WHERE
            t2.filename = 'saplogon.exe'
            and
            t2.fileversion ='7100.3.13.1045')
```

I managed to get me my output with my second attempt, however the resulting SQL is probably much too complex for the simple question I faced with Version 1

Version 2:

```
declare @tab1 table (
    resourceid int,
    filename char(255),
    fileversion char(255)
    )

insert into @tab1(t1.resourceid,t1.filename,t1.fileversion)
select
    t1.resourceid,
    t1.FileName,
    t1.FileVersion    
    from v_GS_SoftwareFile as t1
where 
    t1.filename = 'iexplore.exe'
    and
    t1.fileversion < '8'

select distinct
    temp.resourceid,
    temp.filename as 'IE',
    temp.fileversion as 'IE ver',
    orig.filename as 'SAP',
    orig.fileversion as 'SAP ver'
from @tab1 as temp 
    inner join v_gs_softwarefile as orig on orig.resourceid = temp.resourceid
where
    orig.filename = 'saplogon.exe'
    and
    orig.fileversion = '7100.3.13.1045'
order by temp.resourceid
```

The result looks like this:

```
resourceid | IE | IE ver | SAP | SAP ver
2542 |iexplore.exe | 6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105) | saplogon.exe | 7100.3.13.1045
1544 |iexplore.exe | 7.00.5730.11 (winmain(wmbla).061017-1135) | saplogon.exe | 7100.3.13.1045
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just do a self-join...

```
select t1.resourceid,
    t1.filename as 'IE',
    t1.fileversion as 'IE ver',
    t2.filename as 'SAP',
    t2.fileversion as 'SAP ver'
from v_GS_SoftwareFile as t1
    inner join v_gs_softwarefile as t2 on t2.resourceid = t1.resourceid
where
    (t2.filename = 'saplogon.exe'
    and
    t2.fileversion = '7100.3.13.1045')
    AND 
    (t1.filename = 'iexplore.exe'
    and t1.fileversion < '8')
order by t1.resourceid
```

Comment: life can be so easy sometimes... it still requires a DISTINCT but works like a charm. thanks!

Comment: Happy to help.  The self-join was one of the things that really changed the way I wrote queries - it makes so many things much much simpler.

Comment: @Christoph Voigt - as an alternative to the distinct, you can also try a `GROUP BY` that lists all your columns with the `t1.resourceid` first.  It may or may not run faster than a `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt looks pretty good to me.  If it was me, I'd simplify this by eliminating the temporary table and using a couple sub-selects, so the query would be transformed to:

```
select distinct temp.resourceid, 
                temp.filename as 'IE', 
                temp.fileversion as 'IE ver', 
                orig.filename as 'SAP', 
                orig.fileversion as 'SAP ver' 
  from (select resourceid,
               FileName,
               FileVersion
          from v_GS_SoftwareFile
          where filename = 'iexplore.exe' and
                fileversion < '8' ) as temp
inner join (select resourceid,
                   filename,
                   fileversion
              from v_gs_softwarefile
              where filename = 'saplogon.exe' and 
                    fileversion = '7100.3.13.1045') as orig
  on orig.resourceid = temp.resourceid
order by temp.resourceid
```

I also suspect that the DISTINCT on the main query might not be needed.  Try this with and without the DISTINCT to see.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: the DISTINCT is still needed, yet the results are correct. it's not as readable as JNKs, but still easier to read than my tries. thanks!